# Angular 2 a href target

Tags: html, angular, angular2-routing

I have an array of the following class:

```
export class Ref {
    constructor(
        private id: number,
        private image: string,
        private title: string,
        private descript: string,
        private url: string,
        private urlType: string,
    ) { }
}
```

and in my `html` I call it like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3" *ngFor="let r of ref">
        <a [href]="r.url" [target]="r.urlType" class="reforms-1">
            <img class="refimg" [src]="r.image" alt="">
            <span class="reftitle"><h4>{{r.title}}</h4></span>
            <span class="refline">&nbsp;</span>
            <p>
                {{r.description}}
            </p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything works well except `<a>`. I have an `url` type which sometimes is `_blank` sometimes `_self` etc. So, sometimes it will be router link and sometimes external link (that's why I'm not using `routerLink`).

When I click on the link it's doing full post back in new page when it's `_blank` and that's ok but when it's `_self` browser is doing post back in the same page.

How can I rectify this mistake?

Comment: Can't you remove `[target]="r.urlType"` and put `target="_blank"` ? That would always open things in a new tab. Remove ` private url: string,` from Ref class?

Comment: can't. I'm retrieving it from database

Comment: That's ok.. if you remove `[target]="r.urlType"` and replace it with `target="_blank"` it would work.. Basically you are not using the retrieved `urlType` value from db

Comment: I have stored information about target in database. some of them are _blank, some of them _self, some of them _top etc. so I can't hardcod it

Comment: What is the expected behaivor?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer redirect in expected url without full postback. I want it to be as single page app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `routerLink`. A plain `<a href="...">` is handled by the browser, not by Angular.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3" *ngFor="let r of ref">
        <a *ngIf="r.urlType !== 'routerLink'" [href]="r.url" [target]="r.urlType" class="reforms-1">
            <img class="refimg" [src]="r.image" alt="">
            <span class="reftitle"><h4>{{r.title}}</h4></span>
            <span class="refline">&nbsp;</span>
            <p>
                {{r.description}}
            </p>
        </a>
        <a *ngIf="r.urlType == 'routerLink'" [routerLink]="r.url"> ... </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use attribute data binding:

```
<a [href]="r.url" [attr.data-target]="r.urlType" class="reforms-1">
```

This should work.